# Filter to a WFS relate table

Tags: gis, openlayers, geoserver

I have a Geoserver WFS service and my point is I want to use OpenLayers to show the information of a relate table, with multiple rows for each feature of the WFS, in a popup.

Anyone knows if it is possible to do this? I think an option could be `CQL_FILTER` but I don't know if I can use it to filter rows in another when I click in a feature from the WFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *technically* correct (i.e. hard) way to do this is to set up a [complex feature datastore](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/complex-features.html) with the joined tables in it.

The quick and dirty (i.e. simple) way would be to create a view across the joined tables (either in the DB or in [GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html)) that will return a feature for each row of the view.

Unfortunately you can't use a CQL filter for cross table joins. If both your tables are stored in GeoServer as layers then you could use the [`cross layer`](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html) filtering plugin. But I don't think this will help in your use case.

Comment: Ok, i think i'll try the hard way and if not the second option... Thanks for the help @iant.

Comment: It cost me more that I thought, but I get it finaly. Tanks very much @iant